# Deleting fixed number of data from file in java or android

Tags: java, android, android-file

my question is very clear. As per current API we can delete whole file or delete whole content of file. But my need is only deleting fixed number of bytes ( data ) from a file. If i have file of size 30MB. I wanna delete 2MB of data (from starting position not from ending position). So my file will reduce to 28MB. Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't try anything.. because this concept is possible in C but not in java.

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal: I have to use only one file. Because in another thread i am adding some data to this file. My file size crossing it's limits. So i have to delete some data from starting position

Comment: That's good. Can you give some code to delete line by line from file

Comment: can you post some code where you are writing data on to the file

Answer (score 0):

Use FileChannel.truncate(n) to trim a file to specified size n.

```
         long n = 4096;

         File file =  new File("FILE_PATH");
         RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
         FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();

         fc.truncate(n);   
         fc.size()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

This will let you seek to the place in the file you want, though you can delete or update the segment you want to.

**Edit:**

Well, here is some code:

```
    public class MainClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        long count = 5;//your desired size 
        File file =  new File("C:\\Users\\Pedram\\Desktop\\file.dat");
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
        System.out.println("Before deleting: " + randomAccessFile.length());
        fileChannel.transferTo(count, fileChannel.size() - count, fileChannel);//write data from position(fileChannel.size() - count) to end of file from the orginal file
        randomAccessFile.setLength(randomAccessFile.length() - count);//delete the unnecessary data
        System.out.println("After deleting: " + randomAccessFile.length());
    }

}
```

The trick lays inside `transferTo` method, we just trick it to pull what we want out of it

Comment: Hi can you provide any source code or examples for your answer